# Struggling with Stacked Area Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, area

I have been struggling to create an area chart using ggplot for a while now and to no avail!

Here is my code:

```
strings <- cbind("rstarUS","rstarUK","rstarJAP","rstarGER","rstarFRA","rstarITA","rstarCA")

time <- as.numeric(rep(seq(1,50),each=7))
rstar <- rep(strings,times=50)

v <- variance.decomposition$rstarUS*100

data <- data.frame(time,v)
data <- data.frame(time, percent=as.vector(t(data[-1])), rstar)

percent <- as.numeric(data$percent)

plot.us <- ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=percent, fill=rstar)) + geom_area()

plot.us
```

My data is already in percentages, they are FEVD - but every time I run my code I keep getting lines instead of the shaded area [FEVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqUzl.png).

I am essentially trying to get a stacked area percentage chart

Comment: Without `variance.decomposition$rstarUS` the code is not reproducible, can you post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is with `variance.decomposition$rstarUS`; if you change the value of `v` to something else it appears to run as expected:

```r
library(tidyverse)
strings <- cbind("rstarUS","rstarUK","rstarJAP","rstarGER","rstarFRA","rstarITA","rstarCA")

time <- as.numeric(rep(seq(1,50),each=7))
rstar <- rep(strings,times=50)

v <- rpois(350, 10)

data <- data.frame(time,v)
data <- data.frame(time, percent=as.vector(t(data[-1])), rstar)

percent <- as.numeric(data$percent)

plot.us <- ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=percent, fill=rstar)) + 
  geom_area()

plot.us
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

What is `variance.decomposition$rstarUS` and are you sure you have calculated it properly?

Comment: Hi Jared, just cracked it! Seems my FEVD were duplicating numerous times for an odd reason. I have just sorted out variance.decomposition$rstarUS and it works fine, can't thank you enough!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :)